# How do I import classes in one file to a different file in google colab?

Tags: python

Class 1 (main): Aviation

Class 2/3 (not main, but need objects from this class): Airport, Flight

## In Aviation class file I did the following:

from Flight import *

from Airport import *

## but it did not import the objects from flight & airport since they are in different files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to import the file name. For example if the file name for class 2/3 is `fly.py`. You have to do `from fly import Flight, Airport`. Make sure they are in the same folder. If they aren't in the same folder, try this:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'Path to your folder')
```

Comment: How to put them in the same folder?

Comment: If you’re using vs code, you can drag the file to the folder. Else this link can be helpful, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)